# Conditionally transforming a Json

Tags: json, scala, playframework, transformation

I would like to keep field b only if field a is true.

```
{"a": true, "b": "value"} => {"a": true, "b": "value"}
{"a": false, "b": "value"} => {"a": false}
```

How can I do that with the Reads[JsObject]?

```
val blah: Reads[JsObject] = {
    (__ \ 'a).json.pickBranch and
    (__ \ 'b).json.pickBranch
}.reduce
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple ways that you could do this without completely building the AST by hand. Depending on how many fields you want to pick or prune, one will be more concise than the other. Pulling the transform out to a variable would keep you from creating it every time.

```
val reads1: Reads[JsObject] = new Reads[JsObject] {
  val prune = (__ \ 'b).json.prune
  override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[JsObject] = {
    (json \ "a").as[Boolean] match {
      case true => json.validate[JsObject]
      case false => json.transform(prune)
    }
  }
}

val reads2: Reads[JsObject] = new Reads[JsObject] {
  val pick = (__ \ 'a).json.pickBranch
  override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[JsObject] = {
    (json \ "a").as[Boolean] match {
      case true => json.validate[JsObject]
      case false => json.transform(pick)
    }
  }
}
```